# Is there a callback for Angular Material (tabs) rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, datamaps

I'm trying to integrate a map in Angular Material tabs. To be exact, a map in all the tabs. I'm using [Datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) for rendering the maps.

I made a pen with the demo I worked on, http://codepen.io/sgsvenkatesh/pen/yJbYOj

The code works exactly as expected when I wrap initialisation of map with `setTimeout`. (which I commented out in the above pen in line 128)

The code works perfectly fine when `setTimeout` is applied like shown below.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    new Datamap({
        element: elem[0].querySelector(".map"),
        scope: 'usa',
        projection: 'equirectangular',
        height: 500,
        fills: {
            defaultFill: '#F5F5F5'
        },
        data: scope.dataset,
        geographyConfig: {
            highlightBorderColor: '#bada55',
            popupTemplate: function (geography) {
                return '<div class="hoverinfo">' + geography.properties.name + '</div>';
            },
            highlightBorderWidth: 2
        }
    }).labels({'customLabelText': scope.USData});
}, 1000);
```

In my opinion, the problem is because of Datamaps being rendered even before Angular Material rendering is complete. (probably, that is why the svg doesn't have any width/height)

Does Angular Material provide a callback after the rendering is complete? If not, how do we achieve any DOM manipulation, which is supposed to happen after material rendering.

Please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: try using `$timeout` with no delay... will get pushed to end of digest queue

Comment: Adding a `timeout` will make it a hack, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Just a fact of life in the way angular digests work sometimes. Pushing something to end of stack is not that bad. Angular Material tabs have all sorts of issues in issue tracker also

Comment: Looks like `$timeout` is the only way out!

Comment: Adding `$timeout(fn, 0, true)` is not a hack, it's a badly named feature, `$timeout` does 2 things, creating an actual time-out, and the ability to schedule a task to be run at certain point of the `digest` cycle, similar to `apply`, `applyAsync`, `eval` and `evalAsync`, they all allow you to schedule a task to be run at a certain different point of the digest cycle, whether in the beggining, middle, end, after this or before that.